# No Error Messages or Logs when Gradle Sync Fails

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When downloading a newly generated project and importing it into IntelliJ Idea it says that the Gradle sync failed but gives no additional errors.

Is there a way to see the issue causing Gradle's sync to fail in Idea? (There are no log files made)

Comment: I still don't know how to see more information but I solved the issue by taking random guesses (I was using the wrong JDK).